# Performance penalty for Tensorflow Serving in docker hosted app

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, gunicorn, tensorflow-serving

I am experiencing a large performance penalty for calls to Tensorflow Serving, when the calling app is hosted in a docker container. I was hoping someone would have some suggestions. Details below on the setup and what I have tried.

Scenario 1:

- Docker (version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4) hosted Tensorflow model, following the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker).
- Flask app running on the host machine (not in container).
- Using gRPC for sending the request to the model.
- Performance: 0.0061 seconds / per prediction

Scenario 2:

- Same docker container hosted Tensorflow model.
- Container hosted Flask app running on the host machine (inside same container as the model).
- Using gRPC for sending the request to the model.
- Performance: 0.0107 / per prediction

In other words, when the app is hosted in the same container as the model, performance is ~40% lower.

I have logged timing on nearly every step in the app and have tracked the difference down to this line:

```
result = self.stub.Predict(self.request, 60.0)
```

In the container hosted app, the average round-trip for this is 0.006 seconds. For the same app hosted outside the container, the round-trip for this line is 0.002 seconds.

This is the function I am using to establish the connection to the model.

```
def TFServerConnection():
    channel = implementations.insecure_channel('127.0.0.1', 8500)
    stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    return (channel, stub, request)
```

I have tried hosting the app and model in separate containers, building a custom Tensorflow Serving containers (optimized for my VM), and using the REST api (which decreased performance slightly for both scenarios).

**Edit 1**

To add a bit more information, I am running the docker container with the following command:

```
docker run \
    --detach \
    --publish 8000:8000 \
    --publish 8500:8500 \
    --publish 8501:8501 \
    --name tfserver \
    --mount type=bind,source=/home/jason/models,target=/models \
    --mount type=bind,source=/home/jason/myapp/serve/tfserve.conf,target=/config/tfserve.conf \
    --network host \
    jason/myapp:latest
```

**Edit 2**

I have now tracked this down to being an issue with  `stub.Predict(request, 60.0)` in Flask apps only. It seems Docker is not the issue. Here are the versions of Flask and Tensorflow I am currently running.

```
$ sudo pip3 freeze | grep Flask
Flask==1.0.2

$ sudo pip3 freeze | grep tensor
tensorboard==1.12.0
tensorflow==1.12.0
tensorflow-serving-api==1.12.0
```

I am using gunicorn as my WSGI server:

```
gunicorn --preload --config config/gunicorn.conf app:app
```

And the contents of config/gunicorn.conf:

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = 3
timeout = 60
worker_class = 'gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
```

**Edit 3**

I have now narrowed the issue down to Flask. I ran the Flask app directly with `app.run()` and got the same performance as when using gunicorn. What could Flask be doing that would slow the call to Tensorflow?

Comment: @jtlz2 Unfortunately, no. We have moved to a platform that scales horizontally more easily, thus alleviating the bottleneck through brute force, and I am developing most new models in pytorch.